# Pickleing error: connot pickle Request object

Tags: python, celery, pyramid, pickle

I know That it is not possible to pickle a pyramid request object, but I cant seem to find where I am sending the `Request` object.

Consider the following:

```
@task
def do_consignment_task(store, agent):
    print "GOTHERE IN TASK"
    s = sqlahelper.get_session()
    consign = store.gen_consignment()
    ca = Agents.by_id(store.consignment_agents_id)
    consign.consignment_agents_id = ca.id
    consign.consignment_teamleader_id = ca.ou[0].lead_agents_id
    consign.consignment_timestamp = func.now()
    consign.created_by_agent_id = agent.id
    consign.complete_stamp = func.now()
    consign.sims =  store.sims
    consign.status = "SUCCESS"
    print "GOT BEFORE LOOP " 
    for sim in store.sims:
        if sim in consign.sims:
            continue
        else:
            consign.sims.append(sim)
    s.add(consign)
    transaction.savepoint()
    print "GOT AFTER SAVEPOINT"
    for sim in consign.sims:
        is_reconsign = sim.consignment_agent or sim.consignment_teamlead
        if is_reconsign:
            if not sim.consignment_history:
                sim.consignment_history = []
            sim.consignment_history.append(dict(
                stamp=sim.consignment_timestamp,
                consignment_agent_id=sim.consignment_agents_id,
                consignment_teamleader_id=sim.consignment_teamleader_id,
                by_agent_id=agent.id
            ))
        s.query(
            Sims
        ).filter(
            Sims.iccid == sim.iccid
        ).update(
            {
                "consignment_agents_id": consign.consignment_agents_id,
                "consignment_history": sim.consignment_history,
                "consignment_teamleader_id": ca.ou[0].lead_agents_id,
                "consignment_timestamp": func.now(),
                "modify_stamp": func.now(),
                "consignments_id": consign.id

            },
            synchronize_session=False
        )
        print "GOT BEFORE COMMIT"
        transaction.savepoint()
    print "THIS IS THE ID ID ID ID ID ID : ", consign.id
```

I call this function like:

```
if self.store.finalise:
    try:
        store = self.store
        agent = self.agent

        do_consignment_task.delay(store, agent)

        transaction.commit()
        self.check_and_purge()
        return "Consignmnet is being processed"
    except Exception, exc:
        self.check_and_purge()
        self.log.exception(exc)
        exc_error = "CONSIGNERR:", exc.message
        raise USSDFailure(exc_error)
else:
    self.store.status = "CANCELLED"
    if "fullconfirm" in self.session:
        del self.session["fullconfirm"]
    self.check_and_purge()
    return "CONSIGNMENT Cancelled"
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
EncodeError: Can't pickle <class 'pyramid.util.Request'>: attribute lookup pyramid.util.Request failed
```

I am not sending `self` or `request` objects - at least not that I can see.
How can solve this problem? Am I sending a request object, because I can not see one?

The traceback can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/DxHyQWMF)

**EDIT:**

okay So I have tried to change the data I send to the function - I am not passing a sqlalchemy object and I am making a copy of the `store` object, that changes my code to:

```
@task
def do_consignment_task(agent_id, **store):
    print "GOTHERE IN TASK"
    s = sqlahelper.get_session()
    cObj = USSDConsignmentsObject()
    consign = cObj.gen_consignment()
    ca = Agents.by_id(store.consignment_agents_id)
    consign.consignment_agents_id = ca.id
    consign.consignment_teamleader_id = ca.ou[0].lead_agents_id
    consign.consignment_timestamp = func.now()
    consign.created_by_agent_id = agent_id
    # etc
```

and:

```
if self.store.finalise:
    try:
        # del self.service
        store = self.store.__dict__.copy()
        agent_id = self.agent.id
        print store
        print agent_id
        # print help(store)
        do_consignment_task.delay(agent_id, **store)
        transaction.commit()
        #etc
```

This however still gives me the same error `:|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to serialise a Pyramid request object. When you interact with a celery task you should think of it as an independent process.

Provide it all the information it needs to do it's work. Be aware that you need to serialise that information.

So self.store possibly contains attribute references that may be unrealistic to serialise.

Perhaps create a method on the store object that returns a clean dictionary object.

```
def serialize(self):
    data = {}
    data["element1"] = self.element1
    data["element2"] = self.element2
    data["element3"] = self.element3
    return data
```

Then when you want to call the delay method make sure to use store.serialize() instead of store or the **dict**.